# Configuring Pig-0.12.1 with Hadoop-2.5.0

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have an existing Hadoop client (hadoop-0.20.2) at $HADOOP_HOME. With this version of Hadoop all the client configuration files are placed in the directory: $HADOOP_HOME/conf

To get Pig to work, I have set $PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf. I can then simply run Pig from it's home directory without issues.

I tried to set up a new Hadoop client (hadoop-2.5.0), setting $HADOOP_HOME to point at this directory. For this version of Hadoop I have placed the client configuration at $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

I then set $PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop. However when I try to run pig now I get the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:587)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 7 more
```

Are there other locations that need to be added to the PIG_CLASSPATH to get this up and running?

Comment: I should point out that I can access the cluster using both hadoop clients

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the cause. I was copying over config to $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop that had been sent to me. Inside hadoop-env.sh there was a line

```
 export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=....
```

that was updating the location of the relevant jars to a non-existent location.